Launch Microsoft Store App in the current process to get it's logs and return code
It's possible to start an app from MS Store from cmd using start shell:AppsFolder\BlenderFoundation.Blender_ppwjx1n5r4v9t!BLENDER but the command is finished immediately and Windows app started in a separate process and it's logs are not visible in cmd and it's not possible to get return code from the app when it's finished.
Any ideas how it can be started in the same process, so logs would go to the same cmd window and it would wait until app is finished to get the return code?

Alternative explorer shell:AppsFolder\BlenderFoundation.Blender_ppwjx1n5r4v9t!BLENDER works the same way as start command.
Running shell:AppsFolder\BlenderFoundation.Blender_ppwjx1n5r4v9t!BLENDER directly results in "The system cannot find the path specified.", so I guess it's a special app name that requires some other app (start/explorer) to interpret it.
In theory it's possible to somehow change the app to output it's logs to some specific file and write a script that will monitor until the app process dies and then uses the results somehow, but it's an overkill.
Blender I was using for tests - https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PP3C07GTVRH?ocid=pdpshare
